# Compare md5 after tftp transfer

Tags: c, linux, file, md5sum, strncmp

Because I use the tftp command to transfer an important file, I would like to compare md5 in order to valid the transfer. 
Note : The file has been already transfered in the the example below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input_md5_fd;
    FILE *md5_fd;
    size_t md5_length;
    size_t nbr_items;
    char *input_md5 = NULL; 
    char *file_md5 = NULL;  
    int ret;

    chdir("/tmp");

    system("tftp -g -r INPUT_MD5 192.168.0.1");
    input_md5_fd = fopen("INPUT_MD5", "r");
    if (input_md5_fd != NULL)
    {   
       fprintf(stdout,"MD5 transfered\n");
       fseek(input_md5_fd,0L,SEEK_END);
       md5_length = ftell(md5_fd);
       input_md5 = malloc(md5_length + 1);
       fseek(input_md5_fd,0L,SEEK_SET);
       nbr_items = fread(input_md5, 1, md5_length, input_md5_fd);
       input_md5[nbr_items] = 0;
       fprintf(stdout, "length = %lu B\n",md5_length);
       fprintf(stdout, "contains %s\n", input_md5);
       fclose(input_md5_fd);    
    }
    else
    {
       return -1;
    }

    system("md5sum IMPORTANT_FILE > /tmp/file_md5.txt");

    md5_fd = fopen("file_md5.txt", "r");
    if (md5_fd != NULL)
    {   
       file_md5 = malloc(md5_length +1);
       rewind(md5_fd);
       nbr_items = fread(file_md5, 1, md5_length, md5_fd);
       file_md5[nbr_items] = 0;
       fprintf(stdout, "contains %s\n", file_md5);
       fclose(md5_fd);  
    }
    else
    {    
       return -1;
    }

    printf("file_md5 = %s\n", file_md5);
    printf("input_md5 = %s\n", input_md5);  
    ret = strncmp(file_md5, input_md5, md5_length);
    printf("ret = %d\n", ret);  

    free(input_md5);
    free(file_md5);

}
```

Output :

```
MD5 transfered
length = 33 B
contains a95ef51ec6b1b06f61c97559ddf4868f

contains a95ef51ec6b1b06f61c97559ddf4868f
file_md5 = a95ef51ec6b1b06f61c97559ddf4868f 
input_md5 = a95ef51ec6b1b06f61c97559ddf4868f

ret = 22
```

The input files contain :

```
# cat /tmp/INPUT_MD5 
a95ef51ec6b1b06f61c97559ddf4868f

 # cat /tmp/file_md5 
a95ef51ec6b1b06f61c97559ddf4868f  XXX_XX-XXXX-XX-DD.DDD-DD.DDD.DD.bin
```

X being char and D decimal values.

Why ret is not equal to 0 ? In addition, I don't know from where 34 comes from

EDIT : 
CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED, problem came from md5_length definition. long type has been exchanged to size_t

Comment: Does `input_md5` not also contain a newline, followed by the characters `34`? Otherwise, where does that come from in the output?

Comment: As shows the cat on this file, it does not contain the character `34` ...

Comment: But the variable `input_md5` appears to contain it, right? Compare `strlen(file_md5)` and `strlen(input_md5)`. Are they not different?

Comment: Baldrick, you are right. I added `fprintf(stdout, "input_md5_size = %zu : file_md5_size = %zu \n",strlen(input_md5), strlen(file_md5));` which returns `input_md5_size = 35 : file_md5_size = 33`. That might be the 34 but I never see this character why the cat command ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You risk printing out and comparing garbage since you don't ensure the strings are nul terminated.

You need to do

```
 fread(file_md5, 1, md5_length, md5_fd);
 file_md5[md5_length] = 0;
```

And similar for `input_md5`. Or to do it properly, use the return value of `fread()` to add the nul terminator in the proper place, check if fread() fails, Check how much it returned.

If you also place your debug output inside quotes, it'll also be easier to spot unwanted whitespace or unprintable characters:

```
fprintf(stdout, "contains '%s'\n", input_md5);
```

Comment: I have edited the original code by following your advices. I am still getting `22` as strcmp output value. However the `34` has been removed

Comment: Perhaps you can also show the output of the second suggestion, by enclosing the output in quotes. I suspect one of your files contains a newline, so you're comparing a newline in one of the files that does not exist in the other file. - as is also suggested in the comments.

Comment: The problem seems resolved, just by exchanging md5_length declaration from long to size_t